# While loop in a function doesnt update global variable

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn python functions 
maybe its a noob question but why this loop doesnt stop once start?

```
import time
x=False

def test(z):
    global x
    if z==True:
        x=True

    if z==False:
        x=False


def loop():
    global x
    while x==True:
        print ("1")

test(z=True)
time.sleep(2)
loop()

test(z=False)
time.sleep(2)
loop()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here.  Most of your posted code has nothing to do with the problem you pose.

Comment: You are creating an infinite loop. When you run test(z=True), you are setting x to True. When you run loop, you never have a means of exiting the loop.

Comment: Are you trying to make multi threaded program? Where you check for `x` flag and when `x` is `false` stop the loop???

Answer (score 1):

You wrote an infinite loop, one of the simplest:

```
while x==True:
    print ("1")
```

Since nothing in the loop body changes anything in the loop condition, and you have no `break` statement or other loop exit, there is no way out of the loop.

Comment: so, there is no way to break the loop out of the body? that was my doubt indeed

Comment: There are many ways, depending on your program's intended operation, which you neglected to detail and refine.  If you search in your browser for "Python loop exit", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: I also recommend that you work through a tutorial on Boolean data, as well; there are some basic concepts you apparently have not yet internalized.